# What is the meaning of the subscript operator used in the example in [over.sub]/1?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer

[[over.sub]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.sub#1)

Example:

```
struct X {
    Z operator[](std::initializer_list<int>);
};
X x;
x[{1,2,3}] = 7; // OK: meaning x.operator[]({1,2,3})
int a[10];
a[{1,2,3}] = 7; // error: built-in subscript operator
```

What is `Z` in the operator[] declaration?
What is the probable meaning of the expression `x[{1,2,3}] = 7;` ?

Comment: Whatever you define it to be. It's a user-defined operator?

Comment: Admittedly not the best example, but pretend there's a `struct Z { void operator=(int ); };` in front of that? Otherwise, it doesn't matter what it means - the point is just to demonstrate that you can have user-defined `operator[]` for class types.

Comment: Even better, pretend `using Z = int&;`

Comment: `X` is apparently something that acts like a multi-dimensional array, and `Z` is the type of the elements that it holds.

Answer (score 4):

> What is `Z` in the operator[] declaration?

It is the return type of the function.  It's not used in the example at all so there is no reason for it to actual be defined as something it i just there to show that the function returns something.  Maybe they should but it isn't really needed.

> What is the probable meaning of the expression `x[{1,2,3}] = 7;` ?

I believe it is showing that you can actually pass more than one value but still have it count as one parameter as the operator is defined as having

> [...]exactly one parameter[...]

Since the entire `initializer_list` is the actual parameter it allows you to pass many values.  This could be one way to write a index of operator for an N dimension matrix.  Instead over overloading the `operator()` you could overload the `operator[]` with an `initializer_list` where each value is a index for the corresponding dimension.